# unable to create link the ossfs local directory to the cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I have a web application, using Alibaba Cloud OSS, which is synchronized to the cloud from the local folder in Linux server, I see the files are uploading onto the Linux server but not synchronized to OSS

I have reconfigured the entire setup using the `ossutil` and the `ossfs` but still the same issue

The below is the error I face when I try to run the command

ossfs   -ourl=http://oss-ap-south-1.aliyuncs.com

ossfs: There is no enough disk space for used as cache(or temporary) directory by ossfs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this [guide](http://data-migration.oss-ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/MountOSSasLocalFilesystemusingOSSFS.pdf)?

For me OSS mount on Linux works when I type in command line:

ossfs **bucketname** **/mnt/directory** -ourl=http://oss-**your**-**region**.aliyuncs.com

If your Linux machine is in Alibaba Cloud you can use

-ourl=http://oss-**your**-**region**-**internal**.aliyuncs.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the OSS bucket to the specified directory as follows to synchronize Linux server and OSS.

To mount the OSS bucket to the directory:

```
ossfs bucket mountpoint -ourl=http://oss-your-region.aliyuncs.com
```

For instance, mount the bucket bucketName to the /tmp/ossfs directory. The AccessKeyId is `abcdef`, the AccessKeySecret is `123456`, and the OSS endpoint is `http://oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com.`

```
echo bucketName:abcdef:123456 > /etc/passwd-ossfs
chmod 640 /etc/passwd-ossfs
mkdir /tmp/ossfs
ossfs bucketName /tmp/ossfs -ourl=http://oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com
```

Note: Permissions must be set correctly.